# Chrome extension that focuses items in elements panel

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to develop a chrome extension that among other things, will be able to focus an element in the elements panel of the chrome devtools.

I have been pulling my hair out trying to get this to work today but have had no luck so far.

I think part of the key to cracking what I need is [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html)

> Here are the main differences between the eval() and
>   chrome.tabs.executeScript() methods:
>
> - The eval() method does not use an isolated world for the code being evaluated, so the JavaScript state of the inspected window is
>     accessible to the code. Use this method when access to the JavaScript
>     state of the inspected page is required.
> - The execution context of the code being evaluated includes the Developer Tools console API. For example, the code can use inspect()
>     and $0.
> - The evaluated code may return a value that is passed to the extension callback. The returned value has to be a valid JSON object
>     (it may contain only primitive JavaScript types and acyclic references
>     to other JSON objects). Please observe extra care while processing the
>     data received from the inspected page — the execution context is
>     essentially controlled by the inspected page; a malicious page may
>     affect the data being returned to the extension.

But I cannot find the correct place to send the message to or execute the command in order for this to work I am just repeatedly told the following:

> Error in event handler for 'undefined': $ is not defined
>   ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at Object.ftDev.processMsg (chrome-extension://ffhninlgmdgkjlibihgejadgekgchcmd/ftDev.js:39:31)
>       at chrome-extension://ffhninlgmdgkjlibihgejadgekgchcmd/ftDev.js:16:7
>       at chrome.Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:387:21)
>       at chrome.Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:373:27)
>       at chrome.Event.dispatch (event_bindings:393:17)
>       at miscellaneous_bindings:166:35
>       at chrome.Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:387:21)
>       at chrome.Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:373:27)
>       at chrome.Event.dispatch (event_bindings:393:17)
>       at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage (miscellaneous_bindings:254:22) event_bindings:377
>   chrome.Event.dispatch_

Ideally I would like to use the inspect() method of the chrome console not the $() method.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "XXXXX Ad and Spotlight Debugger",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "A tool to help you identify and debug XXXXXX ads and spotlights in Chrome",
    "devtools_page": "ftDev.html",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "XXXXXX Debug Tool"
    },
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "page": "background.html",
        "js": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["getFTContent.js"],
        "all_frames": true
        }],
    "permissions": ["tabs","cookies","<all_urls>","devtools"]
}
```

Then there is similar code in the popup.js, background.js and devtools.js file that essentially boils down to this:

```
processMsg: function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch(request.type) {
            case "inspect":
                $(request.msg);
                sendResponse(request.msg + "successfully inspected");
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    } /*other cases removed for sake of brevity*/
```

Which when executed results in the error above. I am sure that I am trying to execute the command in the wrong context but I can't figure out how to apply it. In the popup.js file I have also tried executing the $ method as below

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: 'function(){$("#htmlID");}'}, function(){});
```

Any ideas help would be amazing I can supply more of my code if you think it's necessary but I think this pretty much sums up the problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have in the `getFTContent.js` some code which sends some data by means a request with property `type: "inspect"`. Then you expect to handle this data in the `background.js`, in the `processMsg`. Here you should make sure you included jQuery into your background page, otherwise '$' will be undefined. Why do you need $ at all? Still I'm not sure what you want to accomplish, because the devtools does not seem provide any access to "Elements" panel innards. I'm afraid you can't focus a specific element there.

Comment: I think you are possibly correct there however I do not need to use jQuery here, or at ;least I was hoping not to - instead I want to make use of the command line API. If you go to any page (wuthout jQuery I guess would prove this) and type inspect(id) where the id is the id of a div but NOT as a "string" you will see what I mean. Similarlaly the command line API also has it's own $ method.

Comment: The problem is that your extension is not a command line. It does not have neither `inspect` nor `$` by default. So if you want `$(request.msg);` to work, you should include jQuery, or otherwise use `getElementById()`. BUT! Since this your code runs in background script, it will select nothing (it works in the context of extension's page, not tab's). You can select and highlight elements in the tab's document, but you can't manipulate with them in devtools panel. To highlight elements directly in the page, you should use a content script.

Comment: Thanks for the help Stan, I had tried to execute the command from pretty much every environment (background, content-script and devtools page script) but if there's no way to get to the console API then I will just have to remain bitter and twisted about the whole thing :D

I still haven't been able to understand how to select/highlight elements in the tabs document when fired from the content script though. Have you got a link or anything that could help point me in the right direction? I am not in need of editing or maniuplating them - just want them to become focused if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok - so I had a look around at the font changer thing and it still wasn't quite what I was looking for in the end but then I had a Eureka moment when I was looking over [this page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html#method-eval) for about the 15th time and realised that I had somehow missed the most important part on the page (at least in order to do what I wanted) which was this method

```
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("string to evaluate", callBack)
```

It is noted that isn't necessarily a good idea for security reasons as it it doesn't run the code in the isolated world.

Anyway - if I run this code from my devtools' page js-code with the following

```
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("inspect(*id_of_the_div_i_want_inspect*)")
```

Then it will select this item in the elements page of the devtools... it also made me extremely happy!

:D

I don't know if anyone else will ever need/want this but it too me a long(ish) time to figure it out so I hope it helps other people in future.

Comment: At the console, I had to provide a DOM object to `inspect()`, not an ID. E.g., `inspect(window.document.getElementById('thing'))`, not `inspect('thing')`. I don't know if this is also the case calling `inspect()` from within `inspectedWindow.eval()`, but, just in case...

Comment: ...I just tested, and DOM elements work in `.eval()`. from a devtools sidebar pane, but a string ID does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily highlight DOM elements in any tab, where your content script is injected. As an example, look at [Font Selector extension](http://kurrik.github.com/hackathons/09-25-2010/font-selector-chrome-extension.html).

As the source code is available (and thoroughly explained) I'll not post it here. The effect you'll see is that after clicking the browser action button every DOM element under mouse cursor becomes highlighed with red border.

If you want to send some info about selected/highlighted element from the tab into your background page, you can do it via [messaging](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) (you have already used it, as I see).